# Selecting the date of every Monday and Wednesday from a date range

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

I need a formula or a macro to help automate a grade sheet's dates.

We have class every Monday or Wednesday only. I would like to `vlookup` from an input table of each quarter's date range, for example, Sept. 10 - Oct 24. The code should auto-insert the date of every Monday and Wednesday in a row at the top of my grade sheet.

Every year I use the same Excel workbook I built to average and rate the grading with no problem, however I can't seem to get this one right. Currently I have to enter each date by hand.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a formula that will do that.

- In your first column, put your starting date.
- In the next column, put this formula:

`=IF(TEXT(A1,"ddd")="Mon",A1+2,A1+5)`

Which says, if the previous column is a Monday, this column is that day + 2. If it's not, this column is that day + 5.

Then copy the formula into the subsequent cells until you've reached the last date of your quarter.

Here's a video I found that shows how to copy a formula: [Quickly Copy/Paste Data, Formulas, Text in Excel Using the Quick Fill Handle](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9A9gokEwX-s&t=0m50s)

You can format that row so that the dates are displayed how you like by right-clicking the row number (which selects the whole row) and choosing **Format Cells...**.

Under the **Number** tab, choose **Date** from the category list and then pick a **type**. Or you can pick **Custom** from the category list and customize it. I used this under custom:

`ddd, mmm d`

Which is display like this:

**Mon, Sep 10**

This page lists what each "code" means (i.e. "ddd" is the day abbreviated, "Mon"):

http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/CustomFormats.htm

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution is:

=IF(WEEKDAY(A1,11)=5,A1+3,A1+2)

This uses the Weekday function with the parameter (return type) 11, which means the week starts on a Monday and ends on a Sunday.

So if the weekday is 5 (i.e. Friday) it adds 3 days (which = Monday).  Otherwise it adds 2 days (so Monday + 2 = Wednesday and Wednesday + 2 = Friday).

The previous solution only gave you one set of Mon, Wed, Fri.  This formula will allow you to repeat the sequence for more than one week.