# Entering every Monday Tuesday and Friday as a date

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Hi I need to enter the date of every monday, tuesday and thursday on top of a sheet to use as a register, I have looked at the one below and this works for two days, could you please help me to extend it to 3 days a week.  I am using Excel 2010.  Many thanks

[Selecting the date of every Monday and Wednesday from a date range](https://superuser.com/questions/447005/selecting-the-date-of-every-monday-and-wednesday-from-a-date-range)

Comment: -1 What have you tried to adapt it to your needs?

Comment: This will work if you put the right values in G1 and F1 `H1 = IF(G1-F1=1,G1+2, IF(G1-F1=2,G1+4, G1+1))`

Comment: Wow thanks adam works perfectly, and I can see how it works so will be able to work it for the other groups from this.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If you want Monday, Tuesday, and Friday *(not Thursday)* then try this short macro:

```
Sub DateMaker()
    Dim d As Date, K As Long, fmt As String
    K = 1
    d = CDate(Now)

    For i = 1 To Columns.Count
        fmt = Format(d, "dddd")
        If fmt = "Monday" Or fmt = "Tuesday" Or fmt = "Friday" Then
            Cells(1, K).Value = d
            K = K + 1
        End If
        d = d + 1
    Next i

    Rows(1).Cells.NumberFormat = "ddd d/m/yyyy"
End Sub
```

[image]

This begins with today's date.